# Google Calendar API Summary View

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I want to create a summary view of my Google Calendar. Most of my events occur on multiple dates, so I am looking for a way to summarize by name. Instead of looking at weekly/monthly views, I want to be able to see each event name & what dates it appears on. I know the easy solution is to search each event name, but this gets tedious when searching though a long list of events. Is this possible? Hoping for a solution using Python if possible. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Something like...

Event title 1
-1/2/22
-3/15/22
-8/1/22

Event title 2
-1/13/22
-9/2/22
-12/1/22

Event title 3
-2/12/22
-3/1/22
-7/2/22

etc...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.